# Multiple commands after dots in mongo and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to add multiple commands after dots, like in javascript?
Ex.

```
db.collection('users').drop().insertMany([
 ...
]);
```

If not - what is the best possible way to do not redundant db.collection object?

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it works ?

Comment: "Chaining" actually works on the principle that the `function()` ( which is what `drop()` and `insertMany()` etc  actually are ) returns an instance of the type of object you want to "chain" on. In this case it would be a "collection", and NO these functions do not return a "collection" object, so you cannot chain them like this.

Comment: Specifically [`drop()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#drop) returns just a "result", and [`insertMany()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#insertMany) returns a [write result](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#~insertWriteOpResult). Neither of these is a [Collection](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html)

Comment: [`find()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#find) on the other hand returns a [Cursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html), therefore you can chain methods of `Cursor` as in `find().project({ _id: 0 }).toArray()`